# Trouble with getting script to recognize a JSON file in the directory (Google API)

Tags: json, node.js, google-sheets-api

So I am attempting to learn how to use the Google Sheets API with Node.js. In order to get an understanding, I followed along with the node.js quick start guide supplied by Google. I attempted to run it, nearly line for line a copy of the guide, just without documentation. I wind up encountering this: [cmd console output that definitely didn't work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APWyL.png)

Just in case anyone wants to see if I am not matching the guide, which is entirely possible since I am fairly new to this, here is a link to the Google page and my code.

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var google = require('googleapis');
var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');

var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'];
var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH || 
process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'sheets.googleapis.com-nodejs-quickstart.json';

fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
if (err) {
    console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
}

authorize(JSON.parse(content), listMajors);
});
```

I have tried placing the JSON file in each and every part of the directory, but it still won't see it. I've been pulling hairs all day, and a poke in the right direction would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From your command output:

> Error loading client secret file

So your `if (err)` line is being triggered. But since you don't `throw` the error, the script continues anyway (which is dangerous in general).

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

This means that the data you are passing to `JSON.parse()` is `undefined`. It is not a valid JSON string.

You could use [load-json-file](https://github.com/sindresorhus/load-json-file) (or the thing it uses, [parse-json](https://github.com/sindresorhus/parse-json)) to get more helpful error messages. But it's caused by the fact that your `content` variable has nothing since the `client_secret.json` you tried to read could not be found.

As for why the file could not be found, there could be a typo in either the script or the filename you saved the JSON in. Or it may have to do with the current working directory. You may want to use something like this to ensure you end up with the same path regardless of the current working directory.

```
path.join(__dirname, 'client_secret.json')
```

### Resources

- [path.join()](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths)
- [__dirname](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname)